# Unable to pass Jmeter recording test when running the test in real website- one section get fail?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I want to do load test as well as performance test a website and I have recorded user step by step action through jmeter recording by proxy setting. And when I run this recorded test it gets passed all the sections except one section.

During recording steps, it gets filled all the required fields like POST, GET, PATH etc by default as well as like token, session id etc in the HTTP header manager. When user login again its get unique session id and token through Regular Expression Extractor. But my test gets failed when the user wants to accept a task it says unauthorized.  I have attached screenshot. 
This image showing all the steps user will do from login to logout.

[image]

Here steps 2.9 section gets fail.

[image]

Here its showing the response from the server.

[image]
[image]

Please let me know where am I doing wrong.

Comment: The server's response is not very interesting or informative. What was the request? Compare the request in the recording against the request when the test runs. It may be worth recording the test again (up to and including the failing request) and then comparing that request against the other two. Generally, this is just test debugging.

Comment: Please do not show everything as screenshots. They can be difficult to read, they cannot be searched.

Comment: @AdrianHHH well, I have recorded again and runt the test but its get fails in the same section. I wish I could add a test result screenshot.

Comment: @AdrianHHH well, when I recorded its send as a post JSON format key value and it was the ajax request and user accept the job and I think its send those data to the SQL DB but that section did not record with JMeter. Its gives only a success message that Task has been accepted.

Comment: @AdrianHHH and when I run the test again obviously that task is no more available so I changed the id and job name etc according to the task name in the body data of the POST request so that it can find the task there and can accept but still failed. Definitely, am doing somewhere wrong. Hope someone can give me hints where am doing wrong with this test. Thank you.

Comment: As per my first comment. Compare the requests (including the JSON) in the two or more recordings and the test run. Look for values that differ and then work out what those value are or where they come from. You mention a database and something that did not record with JMeter, so how did you make that part of the test? Perhaps that is where the problem lies and there is nothing in the question to about that part of the system so any answer here can only be guesswork or hints.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple possible issues with your test:

1. Location of the [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) and other [Post](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and [Pre-Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#preprocessors). According to [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide) they are applied to all your Samplers so please double check if this is something you're looking for. If you want to apply the Post-Processor to a single sampler - you need to move it to be **a child** of the particular sampler
2. [Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting so consider converting your Beanshell test elements into JSR223 ones
3. Since JMeter 3.0 there is [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) which you should be using instead of the plugins

In general [HTTP status 401](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401) means `Unauthorized` so double check that your test is doing what it is supposed to be doing using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener. You might also want to double check [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) values using [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) as it might be the case that the variables are being overwritten with something you don't expect due to the aforementioned Scoping Rules potential issue